# Haskell - Creating constraints and applying to datatypes

Tags: haskell

I'm trying out the creation of class constraints and applying to new data types, but I could not get this code to type check.  Could someone help?  Where did I go wrong?

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
class NewConstraint a where
  getTrue :: a -> Bool
newtype Identity a = Identity a
  deriving (Eq, Show, Num)
instance (Num a, NewConstraint a) =>
  NewConstraint (Identity a) where
    getTrue x = True
test :: Bool
test = getTrue (Identity 1)
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? What is it?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, thanks, could you explain if I'm using the pragma `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` correctly?  This pragma seems to be why I can include `deriving Num` for `newtype Identity a = Identity a`.  I included that thinking I could get `Identity a` to type check with `Num a`, but it didn't work and I'm not sure why..

Comment: That sounds like like a whole separate question. Please post it as such.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, ok, I've posted a new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68117846/haskell-generalizednewtypederiving-pragmas-interaction-with-constraints-and-d.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems here: missing instance constraints and polymorphic numeric literals.

---

**First up:** missing instance constraints.

When you write code like this:

```
instance NewConstraint a => NewConstraint (Identity a) where
```

It means "*every type of the shape `Identity a`, for every possible `a`, has an instance of `NewConstraint`; but the `a` in question must also have an instance  of `NewConstraint`*"

So when you write `getTrue (Identity 1)`, the compiler looks for an instance of `NewConstraint` and finds one for `Identity a`. But what is `a`? Well, it's an integer number, so let's say it's `Int`.

But your instance declaration says that `a` must have an instance of `NewConstraint`. So the compiler now looks for an instance of `NewConstraint Int`. And doesn't find it. So it gives you an error.

To fix this, either add an instance `NewConstraint Int`, like this:

```
instance NewConstraint Int where getTrue _ = True
```

Or remove the `NewConstraint` constraint from your `Identity a` instance, like this:

```
instance Num a => NewConstraint (Identity a) where
```

---

**Second:** polymorphic numeric literals.

In Haskell, numeric literals like `1`, `5`, or `42` don't have a concrete type. They have type `Num a => a`, which means "*any type `a`, as long as it has an instance of `Num`*"

So when you write `1`, what type is it? Could be `Int` (like I suggested above), could be `Double`, could be `Complex`. The compiler has no way to know what you meant.

Normally there is some other source from which to infer the type. Perhaps the numeric literal is passed to some function as a parameter, and that function expects an `Int`. Well, then the compiler could tell that you meant `Int`.

But in your case there is no such source. So the compiler doesn't know.

So to help the compiler out, you must specify the type, like this:

```
test = getTrue (Identity (1 :: Int))
```

---

**Finally** note that if you remove the `NewConstraint a` constraint from your instance `NewConstraint (Identity a)`, then you don't have to specify the type of `1 :: Int`.

Yes, the compiler still won't know the type of `1`, but it won't care. It doesn't need to find an instance of `NewConstraint a`, so doesn't need to know what `a` is.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the following code, and it seems that the compiler can default to `test :: Identity Integer` when I do `:t test`:  `class NewConstraint a where getTrue :: a -> a`;
`newtype Identity a = Identity a deriving (Show)`;
`instance NewConstraint (Identity a) where getTrue x = x`;
`test = getTrue (Identity 1)`

Comment: GHCi has wider defaulting rules than GHC. This is done on purpose, to allow testing smaller functions without their context. You can make GHC work the same way by enabling `ExtendedDefaultRules`. See [the docs](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#type-defaulting-in-ghci).