# Haskell - GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving pragma's interaction with constraints and datatypes

Tags: haskell

This is a question arising from my code at:

[Haskell - Creating constraints and applying to datatypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68102289/haskell-creating-constraints-and-applying-to-datatypes)

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
class NewConstraint a where
  getTrue :: a -> Bool
newtype Identity a = Identity a
  deriving (Eq, Show, Num)
instance (Num a, NewConstraint a) =>
  NewConstraint (Identity a) where
    getTrue x = True
test :: Bool
test = getTrue (Identity 1)
```

Is my use of the `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` pragma correct?  I had intended for `Identity a` to take on `Num a` characteristics without doing up a `Num a` constrained instance for `NewConstraint`, but it didn't work.  Is this approach possible?  Where did I go wrong?

UPDATE on 30 June 2021

This is my current code:

```
class NewConstraint a where
  getTrue :: a -> a
newtype Identity a = Identity a
  deriving (Show)
instance NewConstraint (Identity a) where
  getTrue x = x
-- test :: Identity Integer
test = getTrue (Identity 1)
```

It works without the need for `{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}`.  When is the pragma needed?

Comment: How did it "not work"? What did you expect to happen and what did happen instead?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, I expected  `newtype Identity a = Identity a deriving (Eq, Show, Num)`; `instance NewConstraint a => NewConstraint (Identity a) where` to work, but it didn't.  I'm not sure if I've used the `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` pragma correctly?..

Comment: What does it mean for it to "work"?

Comment: So to clarify: I am 99% sure that you misunderstand what `Num` actually means, but I'm not sure in what way you misunderstand it exactly, so I can't write an answer until you clarify that. This is why I'm asking clarifying questions. Please describe exactly what went wrong, how do you know that it went wrong, etc.

Comment: A note to would-be answerers: don't make the same mistake I did! Click the provided link, and make sure you're not answering that question (which has the identical code snippet, and where the answer addresses the existing problem with it). At least the question asker believes that the question is different -- let's work out why.

Comment: @maxloo When you say “I expected [...] to work but it didn’t”, in what way did that not work?

Comment: @DavidYoung, my question centres around how the GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving pragma is used, I've tried `newtype Identity a = Identity a`; `deriving (Eq, Show)`; `instance NewConstraint (Identity a) where` and it works without the pragma..

Comment: Once again: what do you mean by "works"?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, by "works", i only mean that the `test` function works..

Comment: The reasons for the `test` function not compiling have been discussed and answered in the linked question. They have nothing to do with `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` or `Num`. So if you want an answer to this question, you need to explain how you expected `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` to help with compiling the `test` function exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instance of `Num` derived via `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` for `Identity` has the form:

```
instance (Num a) => Num (Identity a) where
  fromInteger i = Identity (fromInteger i)
  Identity x + Identity y = Identity (x + y)
  -- …
  -- Similar for ‘(-)’, ‘(*)’, ‘abs’, ‘negate’, ‘signum’.
  -- …
```

That is, if the wrapped type `X` is in `Num`, so you can write `1 :: X`, then `Identity X` is also in `Num`, so you can write `1 :: Identity X` as well; similarly, you can use the `Num` arithmetic operators:

```
x, y, z :: Identity Int

x = Identity 5
y = Identity 7
z = x * y       -- == Identity 35
```

So instead of writing `Identity 1`, which has the type `Identity Integer` by the defaulting of `Num a => a` to `Integer`, you can write just `1`. For illustration, if you remove the ambiguous `Num a` & `NewConstraint a` constraints from the `NewConstraint (Identity a)` instance, then you can write:

```
test :: Bool
test = getTrue (1 :: Identity Int)
```

Or, with the `PartialTypeSignatures` language option, you can omit the inner annotation, which defaults the wrapped type to `Integer`:

```
test = getTrue (1 :: Identity _)
```

You need *some* annotation in this particular case for the same reason that you need one in `show (read "123")`: you need to determine which overload of `read :: Read a => String -> a` and `show :: Show a => a -> String` you’re calling. In this case, you have `fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a` implicitly due to the number literal, and `getTrue :: NewConstraint a => a -> Bool`. You must specify at least that `a` = `Identity b`, whereupon the type `Num b => b` is still ambiguous, but `Num` can be defaulted.